# Mathematically what is the most efficient plan

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms

I have looked at the help center an believe that this is on topic based on this being somewhat a 'Mathematical problems such as one might come across in a course or textbook' as detailed here https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

I need to find the most efficient method of producing 77 trolleys consisting of 8 products from 3 production lines in 8 hours or less.

If I were running this on a single production line the total time would be 19 hours, 50 minutes.

The image below is a representation of the data that I have to work with.

[image]

The following constraints apply.

1. A buffer must be complete before changing to a new product or removing an item from the buffer line. In this scenario there is one buffer available per product.  For instance If production line 1 was running three products, there would be three buffers available to this production line.

A buffer is the line where the product goes once it has been made \ put together. A buffer line cannot be emptied until it has reached its maximum fill level. In this example the max number of products per buffer is 75.

2. We have to build a trolley at a time. So, when product one is run from production line 1, to buffer 1 this could fill 4 trolleys. Where product 8, can only product 1.5 trolleys per production line and buffer.

My current thought process is to split the entire job into smaller jobs of two 3's and a two, and then run them through one at a time.

Any and all help in this matter is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem, but have you considered linear programming? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming

Comment: I have not considered this, and will look into it now. What is it that you didnt understand so that I can try and explain it better

Comment: I think you could describe what actually is going on much more clearly.  I don't know what a buffer is, for example. What is the relationship between shelves and trolleys? (You only mention shelves once.) It is not clear what you mean by "most efficient method".

Comment: To be honest, this doesn't look like a fun problem to solve (just my perspective), so I'm not personally interested in solving it for you.  Taking some time to write out a fuller description of what is happening, and how the data connects with it (e.g., what does "production per item" mean?), might make it more appealing to others.  Everyone has different tastes. Cheers!

Comment: I will edit the question in a moment, but a buffer is the line where the product goes once it has been assembled.  in this instance there are 75 products to a buffer line because of the size of the product and the gap required between each product.  Re shelves, I will remove that to make it easier to deal with one variable in this instance

Comment: And you're right its not a fun problem hence why I need some help.